# Constrain results from core.logic query?

Tags: graph, clojure, clojure-core.logic

I am trying to model a graph using core.logic and would like to match all nodes that have edges to two other nodes. I have come up with the below but it returns two results instead of the desired one, as [2 3 4] and [2 4 3] are equivalent. How would I constrain the query to only return the desired result?

```
(use 'clojure.core.logic.pldb)

(db-rel edge a b)

(def g
  (db
   [edge 1 2]
   [edge 2 3]
   [edge 3 4]
   [edge 2 4]))

(with-db g
  (run* [q]
    (fresh [x y z]
      (edge x y)
      (edge x z)
      (!= y z)
      (== q [x y z]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't care which of the two results you get, then the easiest thing to do is to replace the (run* [q] call with (run 1 [q], where the 1 indicates you only want one result returned.

Comment: Yeah, thought about that but that will not work as the query might return multiple true hits, ie. more than one node with "descendants".

Comment: If your position is that you are getting the right answer, but also some answers that are wrong in some way, the easiest (and most correct) thing to do is to add constraints to your query that filter out those results that you don't want.

Comment: Yes, the think is I cannot figure out what those constraints should be. The suggested answer might work, but it is just a weird way of expressing that a 3-2-4 subgraph and a 4-2-3 subgraph are equivalent.

Comment: In your example, both the solutions are correct, in the sense that they are both solutions to the query "which nodes have edges to (at least) two other nodes?"

Comment: What I think you want is to figure out which nodes have edges to (at least) two other nodes, and then to return a distinct set of those nodes. In that case, you can just run the results of your query through (into #{} (map first your-results))

Comment: I need the nodes that the "parent" node is connected to too.

Comment: If you want to keep the other nodes as well, then you can create a map which has your distinct nodes as keys, and the nodes to which the nodes connect as the values of the keys. Like so: (reduce (fn [a i] (assoc a (first i) (rest i))) {} your-results)